# T-SQL - Check if view is SCHEMABINDING

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, schemabinding

I tried to google it, but didn't found an answer...

Is it possible to check if view is created with SCHEMABINDING?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You've already accepted another answer, but the [`OBJECTPROPERTY()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105.aspx) can answer this directly:

```
select objectproperty(object_id('viewname'), 'IsSchemaBound')
```

Note also that `sys.sql_dependencies` is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174402.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I changed the accepted answer to yours, it is more clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a direct way, but you could run

```
select * 
from sys.sql_dependencies
where class = 1 and object_id = object_id('<view name>');
```

If it returns values, the view is bound.